# How do I get the variable values from a URL

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

I am writing a Vue app that talks to a Wordpress back end. I am using a plugin called simple-jwt-login and I am able to log in by making a GET request using axios:

```
        const login = await axios.get("http://localhost:10019/", {
          params: {
            rest_route: "/simple-jwt-login/v1/autologin",
            JWT: token,
          },
        });
```

The plugin gives you certain variables that you can include in your redirect URL but this is on the back end and I do not use the redirect option because I am using Vue on the front end and want to do the redirect there once logged in.
[image: simple-jwt-login settings for log in]

How do I get those variable values in the front end so i can display the user's name and other information to the user?

Comment: What does the `login` object look like? Are you receiving a JWT?

Comment: Well I have to make two calls to two different endpoints and the first is to get the token and the second is to use the token to log the user in. I only get back a message "User has been logged in"